# Element in no prime ideal $\iff$ it is a unit

Tags: commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I was working through Atiyah & MacDonald, chapter 1 section 1 problem 17 part iii) where it says

> Let $R$ be a ring and $f\in R$. Define $V(f)$ to be all elements of $\mathfrak{p}\in\text{Spec}(R)$ with $f\in\mathfrak{p}$. Define $X_f$ to be the complement of $V(f)$ in $\text{Spec}(R)$.
>
> iii) Show $X_f=\text{Spec(R)} \iff$ $f$ is a unit.

I've seen multiple answers regarding this question but, most use $f\notin \mathfrak{p}\,(\forall\mathfrak{p}\in \text{Spec}(R))\iff f\in R^\times$. I haven't been able to find a proof of the above. Does anyone have reference (or proof) of this?

Edit: I would still be interested in a proof that does not involve Zorn's Lemma, if there is one. If the ring is Noetherian the proof stands. However, is there proof of the general case or-counter examples?

Comment: Have you tried to prove it?

Comment: @JakeLevinson Yes. I can not come up with a good reason to say if an element is not a unit then it must be a zero divisor.

Comment: It doesn't need to be a zero-divisor -- some confusion here.

Comment: @JakeLevinson True. But I wasn't taking the proof that $\langle f \rangle$ was contained in a maximal ideal assuming $f$ is not a unit. Now I am just  pondering whether there are rings where $x\nmid 1$ generates an ideal that is contained in no maximal ideal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that if $f$ is in no prime ideals, then it doesn't lie in any maximal ideals either.  However, any non-trivial ideal is contained in a maximal ideal (by Zorn's Lemma).  Therefore, $\langle f \rangle$ is equal to the whole ring $R$.  However, $1\in \langle f \rangle$  implies $1 = fr$ for some $r\in R$, as desired.

According to the first answer of this [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/98549/existence-of-prime-ideals-and-axiom-of-choice) and its commentary, the statement that any proper ideal in a unital ring is contained in some prime ideal is equivalent to the Boolean Prime Ideal axiom (weaker than choice)
, without which there are unital rings with no prime ideals whatsoever.  Any non-unit elements in such a ring would provide a counterexample, so this axiom at least is necessary for the result to be true.

Comment: This is it. I wonder if it is possible to construct a ring where this is not true (I accept the proof that every non-trivial ideal is contained in a maximal ideal) but, if Zorn's Lemma was not used is this result still provable?

Comment: It does in your example. That is okay.

Comment: I have elaborated my answer vis-a-vis which axioms are necessary in the proof.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much!